# JpaRepository: Spring Sort for runtime query variabels

Tags: sql, hibernate, sorting, jpa, spring-data-jpa

There is my plain sql query:

```
SELECT id, title, 
IF(o.fixed_on_top = 1 AND o.fixing_on_top_day_counter > 5, 1 ,0) actual_fixed_on_top 
FROM orders o
ORDER BY actual_fixed_on_top DESC, publication_date DESC;
```

How can I perform sorting like this on JpaRepository?
Maybe using Criteria API? 
But I dint find any examples..
Thanks!

EDIT:
ok, studied different ways, and convinced that it cant be implemented through Criteria API (but it is a pity)

One working variant: Native SQL Query, i am sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
public class MyEntitySpecifications {

    public static Specification<MyEntity> GetByPageSpecification() {
        return new Specification<MyEntity>() {

            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<MyEntity> root, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder cb) {

                Expression fixingExpr = cb.greaterThan(root.get(MyEntity_.fixingDueDate), new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC));
                cq.orderBy(new OrderImpl(cb.selectCase().when(fixingExpr, 1).otherwise(0), false));

                return cb...;
            }

        };
    }
}
```

The main idea is using case expression instead of simple logical.
plain sql equuivalent is:

```
select ...
from my_entity e
where ...
order by case when e.fixing_due_date > now() then 1 else 0 end desc
```

So we can build dynamic queries with criteria api specifications as well. 
No direct access to EntityManager, no plain sql.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using the [QueryDslPredicateExecutor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/querydsl/QueryDslPredicateExecutor.html) which provides the following two method:

```
Iterable<T> findAll(Predicate predicate, OrderSpecifier<?> ... orderSpecifiers);

Page<T> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable);
```

The [PageRequest](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html) class implements `Pageable` and allows you to specified the sorting you want.

You could also add a `Pageable` parameter in a `@Query` annotated method on a regular `JpaRepository` and Spring Data Jpa will do the rest, for example:

```
@Query("select e from SomeEntity e where e.param1 = :param1")
public Page<SomeEntity> findSome(@Param("param1") String param1, Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 0):

(sorry cannot comment yet)

I recently had the same issue.
The only solution worked for me, is to specify the order on the relationship. 
I don't see a relationship in your query

example:

```
@OneToMany
@OrderBy("date")
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring data jpa does understand `order by` see [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html)

`findByAgeOrderByLastnameDesc()` will be parsed into `where x.age = ?1 order by x.lastname desc` clause.

I see your case a bit complicated, but you can do JQPL with [@Query](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.query-methods.at-query) annotation, Sample:

```
@Query("SELECT o FROM Order o WHERE write your clause ORDER BY o.something desc")
public Order findByCustomPK(@Param("paramIfNeeded"));
```

Comment: What about actual_fixed_on_top parameter, calculated in runtime and take part in ORDER BY clause? Thanks!

Comment: yes, it does. see the sample `findByAgeOrderByLastnameDesc()` makes `find by age order by last name desc`, that is how it parses.

Comment: Actually this is not an answer.