# Spring data: order by result of condition for each row

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api, querydsl

In plain SQL is possible to calculate runtime variables, like IF/SUM for each row, and possible to use it for ordering.
My question about possibility of doing things like that in QueryDSL/Criteria API
**Is it possible or not?**

I have entity called OrderSummary, with following fields:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class OrderSummary implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "fixing_due_date")
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    private DateTime fixingDueDate;
    ...
}
```

And I have generated Q-class.

So i try to apply for ordering following specifier:

```
private OrderSpecifier<Boolean> order() {
    QOrderSummary orderSummary = QOrderSummary.orderSummary;
    DateTimePath<DateTime> fixingDueDate = orderSummary.fixingDueDate;
    BooleanExpression be = fixingDueDate.after(DateTime.now());
    OrderSpecifier<Boolean> ose = be.desc();
    return ose;
}
```

But i got exception "com.mysema.query.types.PredicateOperation cannot be cast to com.mysema.query.types.Path"

I asked a similar question (about CriteriaAPI), but unfortunatelly nobody understand the real meaning of: 
[JpaRepository: Spring Sort for runtime query variabels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25144593/jparepository-spring-sort-for-runtime-query-variabels)

The question about order by result of condition for each row.

Thanks!

Comment: which versions of spring-data-jpa, spring-data-commans and QueryDSL are you using?

Comment: spring-data-jpa: 1.6.2.RELEASE; querydsl: 3.6.1;  hibernate: 4.0.1.Final

Comment: There has been an issue with QueryDSL used for sorting which was resolved in latest Evans and Dijkstra releases. Can you try upgading to spring-data-jpa 1.6.5 or 1.7.2 and see if the error still exists - I case would I'd recommend opening a ticket on the bug tracker.

Comment: Thank you Christoph. So, I put the question to querydsl user group and got rich explanation about it: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/querydsl/fiCMKVt7SFs

Comment: Bug is fixed, but i found the solution in my preferred way with JPASpecificationExecutor. If you are interested, you could follow by link in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was found, but in my preferred way with jpa specifications: 
[JpaRepository: Spring Sort for runtime query variabels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25144593/jparepository-spring-sort-for-runtime-query-variabels/28560210#28560210)